# On any iOS Mobile Devices: Inputs within iFrames have issues determining when input is out of focus - Material Design -Recurly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iframe, recurly

**Situation:**

Material Design Floating Labels are stuck with a **class="in-focused"** even when the input is **out of focus**. The inputs also contain an **iFrame** generated from **Recurly** if that helps.

This seems to happen on (Chrome and Safari) browsers for any iOS Mobile device (iPads iPhones any version). Also, the inputs are all iFrames. Sometimes the cursor will disappear (version 9 and below) when you try to tap back into an empty input field as an additional error. The iFrames are generated from **Recurly**.

**I believe there is an issue with Mobile Safari devices where it doesn't recognize a possible Blur event.**

**Question:**
My goal is to remove the **class="is-focused"** from any element that is **not in focus.** What would you you recommend as a solution for this problem?

If you would like to reproduce the error you can see if you go to this url: https://pantaya.com/billing/payment (sign up a dummy account if you need to...) You will see the form that gives these errors.

All advice is helpful! Thank you!

Picture attached to see error:[image]